# PHP SimpleXLSX can not read excel(.xlsx) file

Tags: php, phpexcel

[SimpleXLSX](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx) can not read excel file that generated using [PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter).

Code of XLSXWriter:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.XLSXWriter::sanitize_filename($file_name).'"');
header('Content-Type:   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);

$writer = new XLSXWriter();

$writer->writeToFile(DIR_EXCEL . $file_name) //file path in bracket
```

> [SimpleXLSX](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx) can read manually generated Excel(.xlsx)  file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add those line in SimpleXLSX.php file.

```
const SCHEMA_REL_RELATIONSHIP  =  'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships';
const SCHEMA_REL_OFFICEDOCUMENT_RELATIONSHIP = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships';
const SCHEMA_REL_WORKSHEETRELATION =  'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet';
```